# Is there a canonical list of Minecraft bugs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a good official/semi-offical list of Minecraft bugs somewhere.  I occasionally experience weird behaviors and I want to know if the bug is already known, and I should just accept it since I am playing something in alpha, or if it is a new bug and needs to be reported so it can be fixed/addressed.

Comment: I would change the accepted answer to [fredley's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/109484/17179). The other two used to be correct, but are now no longer used, and have been replaced by the _Mojang Bug Tracker_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Mojang Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa)

This is the proper, official bug tracker, with tickets for bugs, merging, fix-versions, the works. You can submit bugs here straight to Mojang.

Answer (score 9):

**[Edit]**  The new **official** list of bugs can be found [here](http://help.mojang.com/) *(old list is [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang))*.  Anyone can submit a bug or suggestion, but search first to make sure it hasn't already been submitted.