# Minecraft Forge java error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I'm using `minecraft forge` to include shading mods and packages into my minecraft. But for some reason when I try to launch the game I get this error log:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Everything's going to plan. No, really, that was supposed to happen.

Time: 10/28/13 3:57 PM
Description: Registering texture

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.func_130100_a(TextureAtlasSprite.java:203)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.load(TextureAtlasSprite.java:313)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110571_b(TextureMap.java:80)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110551_a(TextureMap.java:57)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110579_a(SourceFile:69)
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110549_a(SourceFile:133)
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.func_110544_b(SourceFile:99)
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.func_110541_a(SourceFile:87)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_110436_a(Minecraft.java:543)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:265)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:509)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:808)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
```

And a lot more, but I just included the summary (there's also the full error log, if needed I will post it)

My specs:

-Windows 8, 64-bit machine. I7-3630QM processor, 16G Ram, NVIDIA GForce GTX670MX
-Java 7 64-bit. (Tried Java 6, didn't work)
-Minecraft version 1.6.4

Comment: Possibly the solution: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/how-do-you-allocate-more-ram-to-minecraft

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` indicates that the process didn't have enough memory.

Comment: Try allocating a minimum of 256 MB and a maximum of 2GB.

Comment: @Timtech How do I do that? I tried following the link that `3ventic` mentioned above but I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini "1. Create a new document and save it as run.bat. 2. type the following and save:

`"c:\location to your javaw" -Xmx2048M -Xms256M -jar "location.to.your.minecraft.exe"`

Comment: @Timtech Minimum recommended for *vanilla* is now 1GB, not 256MB. With shader mods and all the rest, it will be much higher.

Comment: allocating more memory would be the answer, with 64 bit you can allocate more than 4 gig

Comment: Solved :) Thanks a lot guys. My problem now is with the packages, but for now this actual question is solved.

Comment: @3ventic Want to put that in a minimal answer (something like "You're running out of memory, this other question's answer will help") so it could be marked accepted?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Since when minimum recommended mem size for `vanilla` Minecraft is 1GB? I am playing Minecraft 1.7.9 with 450MB allocated, no problems...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support for a modded Minecraft crash issue**](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create a .bat file. Open your Minecraft launcher click on "Edit Profile. In the new window at the bottom it says JVM Arguments check the box next to it then type the values there. I have 6GB of RAM, so I use `-Xmx3072M`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mojang launcher and give it more ram with "Edit profile".
Where it says JVM Arguments enter `-Xmx[amount of MBs RAM]M`.
You have 16GB RAM so I would use `4096` for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating more memory by using Launch4J and try playing with it to add the natives.