# Minecraft crash

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I was playing a minecraft map and it suddenly started to lag then it said `Not responding` then the game crashed.

Here is the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // Hi. I'm Minecraft, and I'm a crashaholic.

Time: 4/9/16 5:06 PM Description: Registering texture

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space     at bml.a(SourceFile:281)    at bml.a(SourceFile:271)    at bml.a(SourceFile:205)    at bme.a(SourceFile:47)     at bmj.a(SourceFile:56)     at bmj.a(SourceFile:38)     at bhd.a(SourceFile:30)     at bhe.a(SourceFile:93)     at bhe.a(SourceFile:15)     at bhc.a(SourceFile:114)    at bhc.a(SourceFile:102)    at bfr.a(SourceFile:615)    at bfk.a(SourceFile:1244)   at bfk.b(SourceFile:1149)   at bfk.a(SourceFile:1002)   at ave.av(SourceFile:915)   at ave.a(SourceFile:325)    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head -- Stacktrace:  at bml.a(SourceFile:281)    at bml.a(SourceFile:271)    at bml.a(SourceFile:205)    at bme.a(SourceFile:47)

-- Resource location being registered -- Details:   Resource location: minecraft:textures/entity/chest/normal.png   Texture object class: bme Stacktrace:   at bmj.a(SourceFile:56)     at bmj.a(SourceFile:38)     at bhd.a(SourceFile:30)     at bhe.a(SourceFile:93)     at bhe.a(SourceFile:15)

-- Block Entity Details -- Details:     Name: Chest // aky  Block type: ID #54 (tile.chest // afs)  Block data value: 4 / 0x4 / 0b0100  Block location: World: (-308,32,-755), Chunk: (at 12,2,13 in -20,-48; contains blocks -320,0,-768 to -305,255,-753), Region: (-1,-2; contains chunks -32,-64 to -1,-33, blocks -512,0,-1024 to -1,255,-513)     Actual block type: ID #54 (tile.chest // afs)   Actual block data value: 4 / 0x4 / 0b0100 Stacktrace:   at bhc.a(SourceFile:114)    at bhc.a(SourceFile:102)    at bfr.a(SourceFile:615)    at bfk.a(SourceFile:1244)   at bfk.b(SourceFile:1149)

-- Affected level -- Details:   Level name: MpServer    All players: 1 total; [bew['TheDoctor90520'/322, l='MpServer', x=-328.17, y=29.00, z=-748.94]]  Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 2450, 2450  Level seed: 0   Level generator: ID 01 - flat, ver 0. Features enabled: false   Level generator options:    Level spawn location:
-311.00,29.00,-750.00 - World: (-311,29,-750), Chunk: (at 9,1,2 in -20,-47; contains blocks -320,0,-752 to -305,255,-737), Region: (-1,-2; contains chunks -32,-64 to -1,-33, blocks -512,0,-1024 to
-1,255,-513)    Level time: 4012401 game time, 25199 day time   Level dimension: 0  Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?   Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)  Level game mode: Game mode: adventure (ID 2). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false    Forced entities: 202 total; [uq['Painting'/103, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-888.50], uq['Painting'/104, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-889.50], uq['Painting'/105, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-886.50], uq['Painting'/108, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=70.00, z=-882.50], uq['Painting'/109, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=69.00, z=-881.50], uq['Painting'/110, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=67.50, z=-880.50], uq['Painting'/111, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=69.50, z=-882.50], uq['Painting'/112, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=68.50, z=-881.50], uq['Painting'/113, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=67.50, z=-880.50], uq['Painting'/202, l='MpServer', x=-368.03, y=66.50, z=-881.00], uq['Painting'/203, l='MpServer', x=-382.00, y=66.00, z=-883.97], uq['Painting'/13, l='MpServer', x=-422.97, y=69.00, z=-886.50], uq['Painting'/35, l='MpServer', x=-411.03, y=68.50, z=-885.50], uq['Painting'/36, l='MpServer', x=-411.03, y=68.50, z=-889.50], uq['Painting'/39, l='MpServer', x=-411.50, y=65.50, z=-877.03], uq['Painting'/40, l='MpServer', x=-415.00, y=66.00, z=-877.03], uq['Painting'/41, l='MpServer', x=-414.00, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/42, l='MpServer', x=-410.50, y=66.00, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/43, l='MpServer', x=-408.50, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/44, l='MpServer', x=-403.50, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/99, l='MpServer', x=-394.97, y=66.00, z=-882.00], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/100, l='MpServer', x=-390.03, y=72.50, z=-892.50], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/101, l='MpServer', x=-390.03, y=72.50, z=-890.50], uq['Painting'/102, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-887.50], uq['Painting'/103, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-888.50], uq['Painting'/104, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-889.50], uq['Painting'/105, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-886.50], uq['Painting'/108, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=70.00, z=-882.50], uq['Painting'/109, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=69.00, z=-881.50], uq['Painting'/110, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=67.50, z=-880.50], uq['Painting'/111, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=69.50, z=-882.50], uq['Painting'/112, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=68.50, z=-881.50], uq['Painting'/113, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=67.50, z=-880.50], uq['Painting'/114, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=66.50, z=-879.50], uq['Painting'/115, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=66.50, z=-878.50], uq['Painting'/116, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=67.00, z=-879.50], uq['Painting'/202, l='MpServer', x=-368.03, y=66.50, z=-881.00], uq['Painting'/203, l='MpServer', x=-382.00, y=66.00, z=-883.97], uq['Painting'/204, l='MpServer', x=-368.03, y=66.00, z=-878.00], vg['entity.MinecartRideable.name'/205, l='MpServer', x=-376.50, y=64.06, z=-807.59], uq['Painting'/224, l='MpServer', x=-364.00, y=52.50, z=-705.97], uq['Painting'/225, l='MpServer', x=-361.00, y=52.00, z=-705.97], uq['Painting'/226, l='MpServer', x=-355.03, y=51.00, z=-698.50], wi['Villager'/227, l='MpServer', x=-362.16, y=56.00, z=-696.72], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/231, l='MpServer', x=-341.97, y=65.50, z=-721.50], uq['Painting'/232, l='MpServer', x=-338.03, y=65.50, z=-724.00], uq['Painting'/233, l='MpServer', x=-347.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/234, l='MpServer', x=-346.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/235, l='MpServer', x=-349.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/236, l='MpServer', x=-351.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/237, l='MpServer', x=-338.50, y=66.50, z=-718.97], uq['Painting'/238, l='MpServer', x=-350.50, y=44.50, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/239, l='MpServer', x=-348.50, y=45.00, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/240, l='MpServer', x=-346.50, y=44.50, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/241, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-695.50], uq['Painting'/242, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-701.50], uq['Painting'/243, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-703.50], uq['Painting'/244, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-702.50], uq['Painting'/245, l='MpServer', x=-326.50, y=32.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/246, l='MpServer', x=-324.00, y=32.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/247, l='MpServer', x=-323.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], uq['Painting'/248, l='MpServer', x=-328.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], uq['Painting'/249, l='MpServer', x=-322.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/250, l='MpServer', x=-323.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/251, l='MpServer', x=-324.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/252, l='MpServer', x=-324.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/253, l='MpServer', x=-322.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/254, l='MpServer', x=-327.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/255, l='MpServer', x=-329.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/256, l='MpServer', x=-329.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/257, l='MpServer', x=-328.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/258, l='MpServer', x=-327.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/259, l='MpServer', x=-329.97, y=32.00, z=-749.50], uq['Painting'/260, l='MpServer', x=-325.97, y=65.50, z=-731.00], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/261, l='MpServer', x=-322.50, y=67.50, z=-721.97], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/262, l='MpServer', x=-333.97, y=65.50, z=-726.50], uq['Painting'/263, l='MpServer', x=-321.03, y=66.00, z=-730.00], uq['Painting'/264, l='MpServer', x=-330.03, y=65.50, z=-726.00], wi['Villager'/265, l='MpServer', x=-325.53, y=68.00, z=-732.31], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/266, l='MpServer', x=-330.50, y=66.50, z=-717.97], uq['Painting'/267, l='MpServer', x=-329.00, y=65.50, z=-698.03], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/268, l='MpServer', x=-326.03, y=65.50, z=-699.50], uq['Painting'/269, l='MpServer', x=-315.00, y=31.50, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/270, l='MpServer', x=-312.00, y=31.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/271, l='MpServer', x=-318.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], we['Zombie'/272, l='MpServer', x=-315.31, y=29.00, z=-736.31], uq['Painting'/273, l='MpServer', x=-317.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/274, l='MpServer', x=-319.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/275, l='MpServer', x=-319.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/276, l='MpServer', x=-318.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/277, l='MpServer', x=-317.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], we['Zombie'/278, l='MpServer', x=-304.50, y=32.00, z=-744.50], wi['Villager'/279, l='MpServer', x=-315.84, y=64.00, z=-726.53], uq['Painting'/280, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-704.50], uq['Painting'/281, l='MpServer', x=-314.50, y=67.50, z=-713.03], uq['Painting'/282, l='MpServer', x=-315.50, y=67.50, z=-713.03], uq['Painting'/283, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-706.50], wi['Villager'/284, l='MpServer', x=-316.09, y=64.00, z=-711.53], wi['Villager'/285, l='MpServer', x=-313.09, y=64.00, z=-704.50], uq['Painting'/286, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-699.50], uq['Painting'/287, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-700.50], wi['Villager'/288, l='MpServer', x=-313.09, y=64.00, z=-699.50], wi['Villager'/289, l='MpServer', x=-307.53, y=65.00, z=-688.72], uq['Painting'/290, l='MpServer', x=-308.03, y=59.50, z=-606.50], uq['Painting'/291, l='MpServer', x=-307.50, y=59.50, z=-607.03], uq['Painting'/292, l='MpServer', x=-305.50, y=59.50, z=-607.03], uq['Painting'/295, l='MpServer', x=-291.97, y=64.50, z=-784.50], wi['Villager'/296, l='MpServer', x=-299.31, y=64.00, z=-738.41], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/297, l='MpServer', x=-296.50, y=66.50, z=-735.97], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/298, l='MpServer', x=-300.50, y=66.50, z=-735.97], vg['entity.MinecartRideable.name'/299, l='MpServer', x=-303.50, y=47.00, z=-710.78], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/300, l='MpServer', x=-293.03, y=73.50, z=-708.50], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/301, l='MpServer', x=-288.50, y=72.50, z=-711.97], wi['Villager'/302, l='MpServer', x=-294.09, y=68.00, z=-670.09], wi['Villager'/303, l='MpServer', x=-293.19, y=68.00, z=-670.09], uq['Painting'/308, l='MpServer', x=-283.00, y=65.50, z=-726.03], uq['Painting'/309, l='MpServer', x=-287.03, y=74.00, z=-707.00], uq['Painting'/310, l='MpServer', x=-285.03, y=78.50, z=-709.00], uq['Painting'/311, l='MpServer', x=-287.00, y=79.50, z=-711.97], wi['Villager'/312, l='MpServer', x=-285.75, y=71.00, z=-711.34], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/313, l='MpServer', x=-284.50, y=65.50, z=-688.97], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/314, l='MpServer', x=-286.50, y=66.50, z=-674.03], uo['entity.ItemFrame.name'/315, l='MpServer', x=-281.50, y=66.50, z=-680.97], uq['Painting'/318, l='MpServer', x=-267.50, y=66.50, z=-666.97], uq['Painting'/319, l='MpServer', x=-245.00, y=44.00, z=-723.97], uq['Painting'/320, l='MpServer', x=-239.00, y=44.00, z=-723.97], bew['TheDoctor90520'/322, l='MpServer', x=-328.17, y=29.00, z=-748.94], uq['Painting'/249, l='MpServer', x=-322.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/250, l='MpServer', x=-323.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/251, l='MpServer', x=-324.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/252, l='MpServer', x=-324.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/253, l='MpServer', x=-322.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/254, l='MpServer', x=-327.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/255, l='MpServer', x=-329.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/256, l='MpServer', x=-329.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/257, l='MpServer', x=-328.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/258, l='MpServer', x=-327.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/259, l='MpServer', x=-329.97, y=32.00, z=-749.50], uq['Painting'/273, l='MpServer', x=-317.97, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/274, l='MpServer', x=-319.03, y=32.50, z=-751.50], uq['Painting'/275, l='MpServer', x=-319.03, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/276, l='MpServer', x=-318.50, y=32.50, z=-746.97], uq['Painting'/277, l='MpServer', x=-317.97, y=32.50, z=-747.50], uq['Painting'/260, l='MpServer', x=-325.97, y=65.50, z=-731.00], uq['Painting'/263, l='MpServer', x=-321.03, y=66.00, z=-730.00], uq['Painting'/264, l='MpServer', x=-330.03, y=65.50, z=-726.00], uq['Painting'/232, l='MpServer', x=-338.03, y=65.50, z=-724.00], uq['Painting'/245, l='MpServer', x=-326.50, y=32.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/246, l='MpServer', x=-324.00, y=32.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/247, l='MpServer', x=-323.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], uq['Painting'/248, l='MpServer', x=-328.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], uq['Painting'/269, l='MpServer', x=-315.00, y=31.50, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/270, l='MpServer', x=-312.00, y=31.00, z=-758.97], uq['Painting'/271, l='MpServer', x=-318.50, y=32.50, z=-752.03], uq['Painting'/280, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-704.50], uq['Painting'/281, l='MpServer', x=-314.50, y=67.50, z=-713.03], uq['Painting'/282, l='MpServer', x=-315.50, y=67.50, z=-713.03], uq['Painting'/283, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-706.50], uq['Painting'/233, l='MpServer', x=-347.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/234, l='MpServer', x=-346.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/235, l='MpServer', x=-349.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/236, l='MpServer', x=-351.50, y=44.50, z=-704.97], uq['Painting'/224, l='MpServer', x=-364.00, y=52.50, z=-705.97], uq['Painting'/225, l='MpServer', x=-361.00, y=52.00, z=-705.97], uq['Painting'/308, l='MpServer', x=-283.00, y=65.50, z=-726.03], uq['Painting'/309, l='MpServer', x=-287.03, y=74.00, z=-707.00], uq['Painting'/310, l='MpServer', x=-285.03, y=78.50, z=-709.00], uq['Painting'/311, l='MpServer', x=-287.00, y=79.50, z=-711.97], uq['Painting'/286, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-699.50], uq['Painting'/287, l='MpServer', x=-309.97, y=67.50, z=-700.50], uq['Painting'/267, l='MpServer', x=-329.00, y=65.50, z=-698.03], uq['Painting'/238, l='MpServer', x=-350.50, y=44.50, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/239, l='MpServer', x=-348.50, y=45.00, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/240, l='MpServer', x=-346.50, y=44.50, z=-692.03], uq['Painting'/241, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-695.50], uq['Painting'/242, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-701.50], uq['Painting'/243, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-703.50], uq['Painting'/244, l='MpServer', x=-345.03, y=44.50, z=-702.50], uq['Painting'/226, l='MpServer', x=-355.03, y=51.00, z=-698.50], uq['Painting'/295, l='MpServer', x=-291.97, y=64.50, z=-784.50], uq['Painting'/319, l='MpServer', x=-245.00, y=44.00, z=-723.97], uq['Painting'/318, l='MpServer', x=-267.50, y=66.50, z=-666.97], uq['Painting'/320, l='MpServer', x=-239.00, y=44.00, z=-723.97], uz['item.tile.notGate'/968, l='MpServer', x=-335.97, y=29.00, z=-741.03], uq['Painting'/39, l='MpServer', x=-411.50, y=65.50, z=-877.03], uq['Painting'/40, l='MpServer', x=-415.00, y=66.00, z=-877.03], uq['Painting'/41, l='MpServer', x=-414.00, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/42, l='MpServer', x=-410.50, y=66.00, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/43, l='MpServer', x=-408.50, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/44, l='MpServer', x=-403.50, y=65.50, z=-878.97], uq['Painting'/114, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=66.50, z=-879.50], uq['Painting'/115, l='MpServer', x=-398.03, y=66.50, z=-878.50], uq['Painting'/116, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=67.00, z=-879.50], uq['Painting'/204, l='MpServer', x=-368.03, y=66.00, z=-878.00], uq['Painting'/290, l='MpServer', x=-308.03, y=59.50, z=-606.50], uq['Painting'/291, l='MpServer', x=-307.50, y=59.50, z=-607.03], uq['Painting'/292, l='MpServer', x=-305.50, y=59.50, z=-607.03], uq['Painting'/13, l='MpServer', x=-422.97, y=69.00, z=-886.50], uq['Painting'/35, l='MpServer', x=-411.03, y=68.50, z=-885.50], uq['Painting'/36, l='MpServer', x=-411.03, y=68.50, z=-889.50], uq['Painting'/99, l='MpServer', x=-394.97, y=66.00, z=-882.00], uq['Painting'/102, l='MpServer', x=-399.97, y=72.50, z=-887.50]]   Retry entities: 0 total; []     Server brand: vanilla   Server type: Integrated singleplayer server Stacktrace:     at bdb.a(SourceFile:309)    at ave.b(SourceFile:2311)   at ave.a(SourceFile:334)    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details -- Details:   Minecraft Version: 1.8.9    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1     Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation  Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation     Memory: 7802112 bytes (7 MB) / 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)  JVM Flags: 6 total;
-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
-Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M  IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0  Launched Version: 1.8.9     LWJGL: 2.9.4    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 GL version 4.0.0 - Build
10.18.10.4176, Intel    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing. Using GL 1.3 texture combiners. Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported. Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported. VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No  Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.   Type: Client (map_client.txt)   Resource Packs:     Current Language: English (US)  Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)   CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00GHz
```

Answer (score 3):

In the log, it says

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

which means that that either the allocated RAM is not enough.

[Check out the answers in this question (on the same website) for more info about how to increase it.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/how-do-you-allocate-more-ram-to-minecraft) (Scroll down to the "New Launcher (1.6+)" Part)

Answer (score 0):

You have run out of memory for Minecraft.  You said you were using a map and that may mean that there is a lot that is needing to be loaded so more memory is needed.  Try moving up to 2 Gigabytes by changing the -Xmx1G option under Java in that profiles settings to -Xmx2G.

Comment: You need Java 64-BIT for this also.