# My world stopped working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]Please help me! Whenever I go into my world, for some reason it just puts me in the void. I don't die. I get all my items, but I can't run commands or really anything. I was using the world as a local server before that if that means anything. Anyway, does anyone know how to fix this? (I did turn off the option that messes things up in video settings. I would type it but it says "it's not proper grammar").

I also searched all over YouTube and Google trying to find this topic but it just shows how to make an entire world a void.

This is my last choice. Please help me I have tried for hours and can't find a way around it.

**Status Updates**

Wait a second, now it shows my world now that I pressed F3. However, no commands work and all I can do is move[image: part of one of my minigames no, looks normal? it's not]

Ok, now my world is kind of working. I left it open for hours and now commands run, but its fps is about 1/2. Sometimes I have to wait 10 seconds for 1 frame to load no matter how I arrange the fps in the settings. I don't get it. It was working perfectly before.

Comment: What have you done to/with your world before it did that? (MCEdit, WorldEdit, Command(block)s,any other stuff...?)

Comment: nothing but for using it on a local server, well i guess i did use a command block to summon snowballs at a fire charge over and over but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with the F3 screen open? It will probably tell a lot about the cause.

Comment: sure here it is

Comment: Try deleting all command blocks usingmc edit

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting seems to be similar to a [Chunk Loading Error](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Chunk_Error) but on a major scale, this can happen if the memory you have assigned is nearing its maximum capacity or your connection to a server is bad. (This is ruled out however as you are not connected to a server)

I would suggest checking if you can assign any more ram to minecraft.

- [Check how much RAM your PC has.](https://www.wikihow.com/Check-Computer-RAM)
- [How to assign more RAM to minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/how-do-you-allocate-more-ram-to-minecraft)

If you cannot assign any more RAM then i would suggest changing certain settings, such as view distance, texture quality (clouds, grass, water etc). I would also suggest installing optifine:

- [How to install optifine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrVfObpbZ-k)

And if all that doesn't work, it may be something such as entity lag. Using the /butcher command will kill all nearby mobs and may free up some memory in order to load the chunks nearby.

Hope this helps.

References: Previous experience, [Minecraft wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki).

Comment: thank you very much for helping me i will try to dedicate more ram to my minecraft if that does not work (it might not because i have other worlds that run fine) i will use /butcher. Thx for your help

Comment: This explains it i only have 4 gigs of installed ram on my computer! Oh my god... this is a bad computer.

Comment: ok i got ram but... it crashes when i move to a certain area and runs at 20 fps when not in that area