# Minecraft Crash: Insufficient memory..."

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

It always says "Insufficient memory for java runtime to continue"
I already have 6GB dedicated to minecraft so I am not sure what else to do to fix the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Comment: If you're using some big modpacks that can push the memory requirements above 6GB.

Comment: This problem needs some more information to diagnose. What are you trying to do that makes it use so much memory?  How did you dedicate 6GB? Are you running a very large world or very big multiplayer server? Windows or linux? Can you post your system information (what hardware do you have?) Have you checked your system monitor or task manager or console if minecraft is indeed grabbing and reserving 6GB of memory? 
Also see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/how-do-you-allocate-more-ram-to-minecraft/120238#120238.