# How do I allow Minecraft launcher to access the memory that I allocated to act as ram?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

So I have a potato pc and I’m broke but I still want to play Minecraft. I can’t allocate but about 3304MBs to Minecraft because I have 4GBs of installed ram. I have about 20GBs of memory allocated as ram to my pc but I don’t know how to allocate the allocated ram to Minecraft? I know that’s a mouthful but I really wanna figure this out

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. Don't know how to address this problem, but I'm sure someone will help you out with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you allocate more RAM to Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120229/how-do-you-allocate-more-ram-to-minecraft)

Comment: Do you have 4 or 20 gigabytes of RAM? Are you talking about virtual RAM?