# Why can I connect to my server using an internal IP and localhost, but not when I use my external IP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, server-administration

I have made a Feed The Beast Ultimate server for a couple of friends. When I try to connect to it, it says `connection refused:connect`, which, according [to this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-in-minecraft/96502) mans that there is no server online, or my router is not port forwarded properly. However, none of these apply. My router *is* port-forwarded correctly, and it's not a firewall problem either (I tested by disabling Windows Firewall for a couple minutes and failed to log in). I **can** connect by using my internal IP and `localhost` *on the same computer*. I have not tested if the internal IP works on a different computer on the same network. So, given the above information, what could be the problem? Did I forget something?

Port-Fowarding Setup
[image]

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't use your external IP to connect to your own computer as it's just extra networking. Can your friends connect using that external IP?

Comment: @3venticNo, that's the problem.

Comment: If your friends can't connect either then you have a problem with the port forwarding setup, or something else is blocking the IP. Check with some port checking tool if the port is properly opened.

Comment: @3ventic see my picture

Comment: If you open up your cmd.exe (Command prompt) and enter `ipconfig`, what is listed under IPv4 address? THAT is what you should put in Private IP there.

Comment: @3ventic Don't have access to a computer right now, will post later.

Comment: Since you can connect with localhost, it's a sign there's something up with your port forwarding setup. I notice in your screenshot you have the private IP set to 184.152.x.x -- typically the private IP would be set to your internal IP address, which would usually be something like 192.168.x.x (given your router is at 192.168.0.1). Are you sure you don't have your public/external IP typed in the private IP box?

Comment: According to google: Your public IP address is 184.152.33.93 - Learn more

Comment: Yes, your public address is what your friends will type in to reach you. You also have a private(internal) address assigned to you by your router, probably in the 192.168.x.x range. That is what you need to have in the "private" box shown on your router config screenshot. You are in essence saying "if somebody talks to the router on port 25565, send them to the computer at 192.168.1.17 (or whatever)".

Comment: Keep in mind that most households have a dynamic WAN ip address, meaning that your public ip will change whenever you reset your modem or your ISP feels like resetting their dhcp server. If you solved your problem and after a while your friends can't connect anymore, [look up your new WAN ip](http://whatsmyip.org)

Comment: I think I set up static IPs or whatever.

Comment: No that is local. your WAN ip (184.152.33.93) will probably change over time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you have your public IP typed into the Private IP field on your port forwarding setup. The public IP is assigned to **your modem/router** by your ISP.

You will want to instead put your private/internal IP in that field. This is the IP assigned to **your computer** by your router. You can find your internal IP (under Windows) by opening `cmd.exe` and typing `ipconfig`. You will look for a line that says:
 `IPv4 Address.....: 192.168.x.x`

Type this whole address into your router's port forwarding configuration as your "Private IP". As Kevin points out in the comments, if the computer you are using as your minecraft **server** is different from the computer you intend to use to play, this applies to the server computer.

This tells your router that when it is accessed on port 25565, it will forward the information to a specific computer on your network, specifically the one you list in that box. Your friends (outside your network) will still use that public IP to contact you.

Comment: Do this on the machine that is hosting the server. If you have a computer dedicated for your minecraft server, minecraft traffic should go to that one, not your regular computer. If you installed your server on your regular computer, forget what I said :)

Comment: So I would use 192.168.0.101?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ if your minecraft server is hosted on the computer that has that ip, yes.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Note that `192.168.0.101` is usually a DHCP-assigned dynamic IP and can change, especially if you have multiple computers on your network. To host a server, you should investigate giving your computer a static IP instead of using DHCP, so that your port forwarding rule won't suddenly stop working if your server gets a different IP assigned to it some day.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Very true! You should make your internal IP static so your port forward doesn't suddenly stop working one day.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is it possible to make a wildcard that allows ANY computer to access 25565?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ The process described above allows any EXTERNAL computer to access the single specified internal computer on the given port. You cannot map a single external port to multiple internal computers, but you can allow different external ports to point to different internal computers on the same ports.

Answer (score 1):

You  could just set the computer that hosts your minecraft server as DMZ. It's really bad practice, because you basically have no safety net for that computer anymore, but it does do the job.

Comment: +1 because it works and is probably easier, but I definitely wouldn't recommend it. You can turn DMZ on and off as needed to help mitigate the risks, but setting up port forwarding will be a better idea long term.