# Why can't I connect to the Nexus?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Nexus is my favourite Minecraft PC multiplayer server. However, when I try to log in, it says "Connection Lost, Failed to login: Bad login".

I tried direct connect too, but that didn't work either, any ideas?

Comment: The server is probably temporarily down.  Have you tried contacting the admin or one of the ops?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Minecraft? Chances are, you are not loggged in properly or the login servers are down.

Comment: Also, confirm in the Minecraft launcher's "edit profile" which version of minecraft to launch, these error could be the result of the server using a different version than your client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

The "bad login" error could be multiple reasons. Here's the first thing you should do. Go to the forums, if available for that server, and see if it's down. Another way to test it is to "ping" the server. I just did that and since the site and the server are both hosted on the same URL, it's obvious it's online. I see nothing referring to it being down.

Sometimes this could be a log in error for Minecraft, this also could mean the server had trouble verifying the account information. Best thing you should do is just wait a few hours and if it doesn't work. Wait 24 hours. If it still doesn't work. Post on the forums.

Hope this answers your question! :D

EDIT: Forgot to add some other stuff. Go ahead and completely log out of Minecraft and re log in. If that doesn't work. Then wait it out!

Comment: In addition to what Matthew has said, you can check Mojang's login server status here: help.mojang.com