# Cannot launch Minecraft: CertificateNotYetValidException

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

What should I do when my Minecraft Launcher 1.3.11 wouldn't log me in? The console output is:

```
Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers.
Please make sure that you are online and that Minecraft is not blocked.
(CertificateNotYetValidException:NotBefore:Tue Apr 08 20:47:05 CST 2014)
```

Comment: Is the clock on your computer set correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Comment: @OKprogrammer Is there a reason you link to that post? I cannot find the OP's error message there.

Comment: @Joachim I flagged it, and then it was changed to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there may be a whole bunch of reasons.

Usually I'd tell you how to configure your Firewall and Internet access corectly, but in the last days Mojang prepared everything for 1.7.6 and actually updated the Version.
So it would be very likely for everybody to notice these lags.

But actually you seem to be different. Watch your last line:
`(CertificateNotYetValidException:NotBefore:Tue Apr 08 20:47:05 CST 2014)`

As you posted this question just an hour ago, and minecraft reports you for sending the wrong time, i guess your time and date is terribly wrong.

This may have two different reasons:

1. One of the users at the PC are cheating on any game and tried to turn the time backwards
   -> Just set the time to the current time. Thats all. [Click here ;)](http://www.timeanddate.com/)
2. Your PC is set to approximately the date 01.01.1970 -> This is most probaly caused by an empty motherboard-Battery. Sure youmay set your date to today and now, but as soon as your restart yur PC it will be gone again. In this case you have got to buy a new battery and get it replaced in your PC. I don't now how old you are or how much experience you've got with electronics, but an open PC may be dangerous. Just open it, if you now what you're doing. Whatever happens, it shall not be my fault.
   This would be a link how such a battery may look like:

[image]

Comment: Once upon a time, :P
there was a difference, as a mainboard is the board to which the CPU und the cache were soldered on, (another board had the in and output-sockets on it and so on..
In fact there were different boards for different tasks to handle.
They all were connected to the motherboard.
So the motherboard is just the one board to rule them all ;)

Seriously, as the battery we're talking about belongs to the above called cache, I was in fact talking about the mainboard.
I'm sorry, but in my opinion there is no difference between main- and motherboard anymore there was no need to edit.

Comment: Im fairly certain windows starts at a different date, like 1600s or something

Answer (score -4):

The game is blocked by the antivirus software or firewall. Try unblocking them using you antivirus software.

Comment: This has nothing to do with that specific error.