# Minecraft server login issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So just 30 minutes ago, I wanted had to leave one of my servers, and re-join it due to odd lag issues. However, upon re-logging into the server, the message **"Failed to login: The authentication are currently down for maintenance"** popped up. I tried and tried to join the server but the message just kept repeating. Everything was fine before I left the server.

I assume that the message meant that the Login problem came from Mojang's end. Therefore, in an attempt to test the authenticity of my assumption, I tried to join several other larger servers. However, the message just continued to appear and the problem persisted.

nest, I went to check on Mojang's services to find out what exactly was going on. Thus, I went to [this website](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/) to check if Minecraft's services were truly down. I then came face to face with this: [image].

I then went to the [Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2074647-failed-to-login-the-authentication-are-currently-down-for-maintenance/) to find out the source of the problem, however, all I got were a bunch of methods to solve the problem. I attempted all of them but to no avail.

Therefore, I am assuming that Minecraft services are truly down and I would now like to know several things:

**Firstly, do you guys have the same problems in the servers you join?**

**Secondly, when you go to [this website](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/), do you receive the same screen as I do?**

**Lastly, are there any methods to fix this problem?**

I would also like to confirm that I am running on the latest version of Minecraft. (1.7.9) and the server that I attempted to join is also updated to 1.7.9.

Comment: Dude, Mojang has been hit by a DDOS.

Comment: @LittleHelper I used to remember, but what exactly is a DDOS attack? Distributive Denial of Service?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Yes, you're right :-).
Servers are back online, by the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

Every once in a while, Mojang's various servers go down for maintenance, or from a DDOS attack (Distributed Denial Of Service). Whenever this happens, Mojang is working their hardest to get the servers back up. The targeted servers are usually the Authentication Servers, Minecraft.net, and/or the Multiplayer Sessions Service. The Player Auth servers will only affect if you log out of a server/minecraft and/or try to log in. Sadly, there is nothing you/we can do to fix this. We all have to bear the pain :/