# MalformedJsonException with a modded version of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft keeps crashing whenever I login (it launches but crashes when I enter a Singleplayer world) . My Minecraft is Premium.

My system specs are:

- Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
- Operating System: Windows 8
- Java Version: 1.8.0_31

I looked for answers but I can't find anything about this kind of crash.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Would you like a cupcake?

Time: 06.02.2015 09:47
Description: Starting integrated server

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 8194
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:56)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerProfileCache.func_152657_b(SourceFile:156)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerProfileCache.(SourceFile:42)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.(MinecraftServer.java:142)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.(IntegratedServer.java:45)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71371_a(Minecraft.java:2080)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiCreateWorld.func_146284_a(GuiCreateWorld.java:230)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_73864_a(GuiScreen.java:225)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiCreateWorld.func_73864_a(GuiCreateWorld.java:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146274_d(GuiScreen.java:296)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146269_k(GuiScreen.java:268)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:1629)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:962)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:887)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 8194
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:480)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:403)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:666)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25.read(TypeAdapters.java:642)
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:44)
    ... 26 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:56)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerProfileCache.func_152657_b(SourceFile:156)
    at net.minecraft.server.management.PlayerProfileCache.(SourceFile:42)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.(MinecraftServer.java:142)
    at net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer.(IntegratedServer.java:45)

-- Starting integrated server --
Details:
    Level ID: New World--------------------
    Level Name: New World
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71371_a(Minecraft.java:2080)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiCreateWorld.func_146284_a(GuiCreateWorld.java:230)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_73864_a(GuiScreen.java:225)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiCreateWorld.func_73864_a(GuiCreateWorld.java:377)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146274_d(GuiScreen.java:296)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.func_146269_k(GuiScreen.java:268)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiMainMenu
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:1629)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:962)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:887)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 8 (amd64) version 6.2
    Java Version: 1.8.0_31, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 180466328 bytes (172 MB) / 266108928 bytes (253 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.85.1240 Minecraft Forge 10.13.2.1240 3 mods loaded, 3 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    FML{7.10.85.1240} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1240.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Forge{10.13.2.1240} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1240.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Launched Version: 1.7.10-Forge10.13.2.1240
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 GL version 4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.2857, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

Comment: Your Minecraft is modded. What mods are there?

Comment: Voting to reopen so we can mark it as a duplicate of [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/96496/28182) as the answer covers this error

Answer (score 3):

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 8194` tells it all.

You can look up this error on its [Google Code Page](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/MalformedJsonException.html)

---

### So, what happened?

There was invalid json formatting/syntax.

### How do I fix?

You'll have to go through your Minecraft save folder and look for the save file that causes the crash.
Then, you'll have to **go through every single file** in that folder, decode its contents into raw text, and look for malformed code.

Malformed JSON formatting include tags' names [not being placed as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280279/parsing-malformed-json-in-javascript)*.
ie. `{Tag:{ ... }}` instead of `{"Tag":{ ... }}`, with `...` representing anything that may be compounded in there.

### How was it caused?

Since your Minecraft was modded, it is mostly likely that a mod has incorrect coding (AKA. a bug) when it comes to modifying the save format (not the extension, the json-content of the `.mca` or `.dat` files).

For example, the [Enviromine mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1292783-enviromine-a-little-bit-of-realism-moved) adds extra root tags to the `player.dat` file, containing information such as thirst, oxygen, sanity and body temperature.

Comment: ok Im going to try that hope it works thanks for answer :)