# Minecraft force closes randomly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I use minecraft 1.8.1, no mods, because if i use a mod it already crashes the moment i join a server. This is what I see everytime it randomly crashes:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x2a1d4a77, pid=2764, tid=7608
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_76-b13) (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.76-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x104a77]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid2764.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

I already tried downgrading my latest Java 8 Update 31 to Java 7 Update 76 (because you guys said 8 is not yet stable) but now it still crashes, but does not say `Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release.` anymore at the last line of the console.

Here is the report file contents:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x2a1d4a77, pid=2764, tid=7608
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_76-b13) (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.76-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x104a77]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x008fd800):  JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=7608, stack(0x00530000,0x00580000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x59d18e34

Registers:
EAX=0x2bd2f7c0, EBX=0x0000001c, ECX=0x2a9b4058, EDX=0x59d18e34
ESP=0x0057f0e0, EBP=0x2bd26080, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x2bd26088
EIP=0x2a1d4a77, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0057f0e0)
0x0057f0e0:   2a9b007c 0000001c 0000001c 00200000
0x0057f0f0:   00000007 2a1d7cb2 0000001c 0000001c
0x0057f100:   00000015 2a1d7f36 2a9b4058 0000001c
0x0057f110:   00000000 2a9b007c 2a9b027f 2bd26d10
0x0057f120:   2a11cdc6 00000000 2a9b007c 0000001c
0x0057f130:   00000007 fcffffff 000c08b9 2a9b027f
0x0057f140:   2a5c1ae9 2a9b007c 2a136867 008fd800
0x0057f150:   00000000 0057f1a8 0057f194 28d49c03 

Instructions: (pc=0x2a1d4a77)
0x2a1d4a57:   fc c1 ee 02 83 c6 01 89 74 24 10 03 f6 03 f6 8d
0x2a1d4a67:   7d 08 89 74 24 18 8d 49 00 8b 77 f8 0f af 71 18
0x2a1d4a77:   0f bf 1c 16 03 f2 f3 0f 2a c3 f3 0f 11 00 0f bf
0x2a1d4a87:   76 02 f3 0f 2a c6 f3 0f 11 40 04 8b 77 fc 0f af 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x2bd2f7c0 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0000001c is an unknown value
ECX=0x2a9b4058 is an unknown value
EDX=0x59d18e34 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0057f0e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x008fd800
EBP=0x2bd26080 is an unknown value
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x2bd26088 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00530000,0x00580000],  sp=0x0057f0e0,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x104a77]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 1848  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawArrays(IIIJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0x018d24f6 [0x018d24a0+0x56]
J 1786 C1 cix.a(Lciu;I)I (416 bytes) @ 0x018b7fcc [0x018b78c0+0x70c]
J 2627 C1 cgw.a(Lwx;F)V (444 bytes) @ 0x019ef4a8 [0x019eef10+0x598]
J 4340 C1 cjh.a(IFJ)V (1216 bytes) @ 0x01d67b40 [0x01d65dc0+0x1d80]
J 4339 C1 cjh.a(FJ)V (137 bytes) @ 0x01d645cc [0x01d643d0+0x1fc]
J 4318 C1 cjh.b(F)V (819 bytes) @ 0x01d54324 [0x01d53ab0+0x874]
J 2781 C1 bss.at()V (897 bytes) @ 0x01a519cc [0x01a51240+0x78c]
j  bss.a()V+72
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1064
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x2c74a800 JavaThread "Netty Client IO #1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6556, stack(0x2cdd0000,0x2ce20000)]
  0x2c749800 JavaThread "Netty Client IO #0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6400, stack(0x2ac60000,0x2acb0000)]
  0x2c749400 JavaThread "Netty Client IO #0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3364, stack(0x34fe0000,0x35030000)]
  0x2c748c00 JavaThread "Server Pinger #1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6912, stack(0x36460000,0x364b0000)]
  0x2c748800 JavaThread "Thread-9" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7980, stack(0x2acd0000,0x2ad20000)]
  0x2c748000 JavaThread "Server Pinger #0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7860, stack(0x31160000,0x311b0000)]
  0x3093b400 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6104, stack(0x2c460000,0x2c4b0000)]
  0x2cb90000 JavaThread "Chunk Batcher 1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8112, stack(0x2ee90000,0x2eee0000)]
  0x2f84ec00 JavaThread "Chunk Batcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7756, stack(0x2ede0000,0x2ee30000)]
  0x2c760800 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=8040, stack(0x2aab0000,0x2ab00000)]
  0x2c760400 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=8148, stack(0x2e7d0000,0x2e820000)]
  0x29563c00 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7804, stack(0x29cf0000,0x29d40000)]
  0x2954c400 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7656, stack(0x29d90000,0x29de0000)]
  0x2949ec00 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7580, stack(0x29bd0000,0x29c20000)]
  0x29422800 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4060, stack(0x298c0000,0x29910000)]
  0x28c20400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7160, stack(0x28e40000,0x28e90000)]
  0x28c16800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7828, stack(0x28ea0000,0x28ef0000)]
  0x28c13c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7060, stack(0x035d0000,0x03620000)]
  0x28c0b000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6472, stack(0x29020000,0x29070000)]
  0x28c0a000 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6848, stack(0x28f30000,0x28f80000)]
  0x00818c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1180, stack(0x28f80000,0x28fd0000)]
  0x00814400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7992, stack(0x00830000,0x00880000)]
=>0x008fd800 JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=7608, stack(0x00530000,0x00580000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0080f000 VMThread [stack: 0x28d90000,0x28de0000] [id=6552]
  0x28c32800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x29160000,0x291b0000] [id=7024]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 25106K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,  22% used [0x03800000, 0x04f23558, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,  10% used [0x09e80000, 0x09fe12b0, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19873K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)

Card table byte_map: [0x27800000,0x27930000] byte_map_base: 0x277e4000

Polling page: 0x00470000

Code Cache  [0x015c0000, 0x01e18000, 0x035c0000)
 total_blobs=4885 nmethods=4504 adapters=316 free_code_cache=24259Kb largest_free_block=24836864

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 307.479 Thread 0x28c16800 4570             java.nio.Bits::long1 (7 bytes)
Event: 307.479 Thread 0x28c16800 nmethod 4570 0x01e0f488 code [0x01e0f580, 0x01e0f620]
Event: 307.479 Thread 0x28c16800 4571             java.nio.Bits::long0 (4 bytes)
Event: 307.479 Thread 0x28c16800 nmethod 4571 0x01e0f688 code [0x01e0f780, 0x01e0f800]
Event: 307.561 Thread 0x28c16800 4572             java.nio.Bits::getLongB (60 bytes)
Event: 307.561 Thread 0x28c16800 nmethod 4572 0x01e0f848 code [0x01e0f9c0, 0x01e0fbac]
Event: 307.561 Thread 0x28c16800 4573             java.nio.Bits::makeLong (77 bytes)
Event: 307.561 Thread 0x28c16800 nmethod 4573 0x01e0fd48 code [0x01e0fe40, 0x01e10040]
Event: 308.776 Thread 0x28c16800 4574             org.lwjgl.openal.AL10::alSourcei (7 bytes)
Event: 308.776 Thread 0x28c16800 nmethod 4574 0x01e10088 code [0x01e10180, 0x01e1020c]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 291.974 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=147 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 105581K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x03800000, 0x09e80000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   4% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0abdb700, 0x0b800000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x09e80000, 0x09e80000, 0x0ab40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81051K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
Event: 291.977 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=148 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 257K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x03800000, 0x03800000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   1% used [0x09e80000, 0x09ec0400, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
}
Event: 298.986 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=148 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 105217K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x03800000, 0x09e80000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   1% used [0x09e80000, 0x09ec0400, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
Event: 298.990 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=149 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 533K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x03800000, 0x03800000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   4% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0abc5638, 0x0b800000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x09e80000, 0x09e80000, 0x0ab40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
}
Event: 303.102 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=149 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 105493K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x03800000, 0x09e80000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   4% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0abc5638, 0x0b800000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x09e80000, 0x09e80000, 0x0ab40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
Event: 303.104 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=150 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 405K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x03800000, 0x03800000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   3% used [0x09e80000, 0x09ee5700, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
}
Event: 306.996 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=150 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 105365K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x03800000, 0x09e80000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   3% used [0x09e80000, 0x09ee5700, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
Event: 306.999 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=151 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 964K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x03800000, 0x03800000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   7% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ac31350, 0x0b800000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x09e80000, 0x09e80000, 0x0ab40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
}
Event: 308.958 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=151 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 105924K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K, 100% used [0x03800000, 0x09e80000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,   7% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ac31350, 0x0b800000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x09e80000, 0x09e80000, 0x0ab40000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
Event: 308.963 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=152 (full 26):
 par new generation   total 118016K, used 1412K [0x03800000, 0x0b800000, 0x0b800000)
  eden space 104960K,   0% used [0x03800000, 0x03800000, 0x09e80000)
  from space 13056K,  10% used [0x09e80000, 0x09fe12b0, 0x0ab40000)
  to   space 13056K,   0% used [0x0ab40000, 0x0ab40000, 0x0b800000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 118828K, used 81113K [0x0b800000, 0x12c0b000, 0x23800000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 33080K, used 19862K [0x23800000, 0x2584e000, 0x27800000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 308.902 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x09b876c0 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025
Event: 308.903 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x09e42c58 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025
Event: 308.965 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x038f6900 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025
Event: 308.965 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x038f6aa0 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:2977
Event: 309.023 Thread 0x008fd800 Threw 0x039ca480 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 309.025 Thread 0x008fd800 Threw 0x039d2738 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1304
Event: 309.033 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x038f6c00 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025
Event: 309.033 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x039f2ed0 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:2977
Event: 309.035 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x039f3030 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025
Event: 309.119 Thread 0x2c760400 Threw 0x039f31d0 at C:\re\jdk7u76\1941\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:3025

Events (10 events):
Event: 303.102 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 303.104 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 306.995 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 306.999 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 308.958 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 308.963 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 309.023 loading class 0x2951c9e0
Event: 309.023 loading class 0x2951c9e0 done
Event: 309.024 loading class 0x2f3b1750
Event: 309.024 loading class 0x2f3b1750 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00990000 - 0x009bf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x777d0000 - 0x7790c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74f60000 - 0x75034000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74cca000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x76670000 - 0x76710000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74ea0000 - 0x74f4c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76650000 - 0x76669000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x75470000 - 0x75511000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x769b0000 - 0x76a79000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x75740000 - 0x7578e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77910000 - 0x7791a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x75930000 - 0x759cd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x73c90000 - 0x73e2e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x758c0000 - 0x75917000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74aa0000 - 0x74aec000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6d88d000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.DLL
0x74a80000 - 0x74a9b000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x759d0000 - 0x7661a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x76850000 - 0x769ac000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x76a80000 - 0x76b0f000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x741c0000 - 0x741d7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74bab000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x73ff0000 - 0x74041000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x74140000 - 0x74152000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x76b10000 - 0x76b2f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75790000 - 0x7585c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x6fe90000 - 0x6ff0d000     C:\Program Files\AVG\AVG2015\avghookx.dll
0x68f60000 - 0x6901f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x67a60000 - 0x67de9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74130000 - 0x74137000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x756b0000 - 0x756e5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x74f50000 - 0x74f56000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x73f60000 - 0x73f92000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x756a0000 - 0x756a5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x727d0000 - 0x727dc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x711e0000 - 0x71200000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x6f300000 - 0x6f313000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x735a0000 - 0x735aa000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\management.dll
0x6edc0000 - 0x6edd4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x745e0000 - 0x7461c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x745d0000 - 0x745d6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x70fd0000 - 0x70fdf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x73040000 - 0x73050000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x6e4b0000 - 0x6e4c0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x6e460000 - 0x6e472000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x744a0000 - 0x744e4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x6d1f0000 - 0x6d1f8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x6ff20000 - 0x6ff47000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x73e30000 - 0x73e4c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73c80000 - 0x73c87000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x72a70000 - 0x72aa8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6ff10000 - 0x6ff16000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x28d40000 - 0x28d8d000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\lwjgl.dll
0x6b6c0000 - 0x6b788000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x6b8a0000 - 0x6b8c2000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x67720000 - 0x67807000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x73520000 - 0x73526000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x75040000 - 0x751dd000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x74c50000 - 0x74c77000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x74e80000 - 0x74e92000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x73260000 - 0x73273000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x74160000 - 0x74169000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x74620000 - 0x74636000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x743c0000 - 0x743fb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74af0000 - 0x74afc000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x72ad0000 - 0x72add000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x72ab0000 - 0x72ac2000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x67340000 - 0x67483000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x73540000 - 0x73580000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x2a0d0000 - 0x2a4c2000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd32.dll
0x2a5a0000 - 0x2a83a000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4dev32.dll
0x753e0000 - 0x75463000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6d200000 - 0x6d279000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x6b860000 - 0x6b898000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x70a40000 - 0x70a7a000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\avutil-ttv-51.dll
0x65980000 - 0x6599d000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\swresample-ttv-0.dll
0x6eb80000 - 0x6ec09000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\libmp3lame-ttv.dll
0x57040000 - 0x57fc0000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\libmfxsw32.dll
0x675f0000 - 0x67720000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\twitchsdk.dll
0x75520000 - 0x75615000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x76710000 - 0x76846000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x74cd0000 - 0x74ded000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x74c10000 - 0x74c1c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x751e0000 - 0x753db000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x29070000 - 0x290d5000     C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183\OpenAL32.dll
0x73280000 - 0x732b9000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x73b80000 - 0x73c75000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x68010000 - 0x68082000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x731b0000 - 0x731d5000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x72a30000 - 0x72a66000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x73a90000 - 0x73a95000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6b030000 - 0x6b11b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1-natives-11044394688183 
java_command: net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username MightyWaffle --version 1.8.1 --gameDir C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\Jayven\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid c0528bc2955a417da7d8b8279028e8dc --accessToken 1337535510N --userProperties {} --userType legacy
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
USERNAME=Jayven
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 2086392k(326576k free), swap 4172784k(1625084k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.76-b04) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_76-b13), built on Dec 18 2014 17:07:28 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Wed Feb 25 13:17:10 2015
elapsed time: 309 seconds
```

Comment: Can you post the report file it mentions?

Comment: Why are you using a beta version of Java? The *expectation* is that these are unstable.

Comment: Check the [list of error codes for Minecraft](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203664/83655) — your error is related to your integrated graphics device (ig4icd32.dll).

Comment: You should try updating your graphics driver

Comment: The error in your console seems to indicate a problem in the audio library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161714/what-does-al-lib-alc-cleanup-1-device-not-closed-mean Perhaps try updating drivers there. It's not a bad idea to try closing other instances of Java running on your computer.

Comment: @TZHX some said in other formus that I should downgrade my Java because java 8 is unstable yet. should I revert back to java 8?

Comment: Java 8 is the official current release. It's possible that Minecraft has some incompatibilities with it, but it's not because _Java_ is unstable.

Comment: It is possible that you are using bad java flags in your launcher. However, I would also have to disagree that 8 is unstable. It's been in testing for a long, long time, and the new Minecraft launcher uses it by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes on launch with EXCEPTION\_ACCESS\_VIOLATION, Problematic frame: ig4dev32.dll or ig4dev64.dll or ig4icd64.dll](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213699/minecraft-crashes-on-launch-with-exception-access-violation-problematic-frame)

Comment: Sorry, disregard duplicate vote, I saw this one doesn't occur on launch.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attempting to downgrade your Java (which was incorrectly communicated to you as 'unstable') you should uninstall all of your mods.  The crash appears to be happening when your Minecraft client goes to render the world.  I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of Java 8 since the version you indicated you were running is actually 2 releases outdated.  Java 8-update45 was released this week, and it is stable.  Then I would suggest trying to connect to the server with an unmodified Minecraft.

Current Stack shows:

```
J 1848  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawArrays(IIIJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0x018d24f6 [0x018d24a0+0x56]
```

This is the the graphics rendering.  `ig4icd32.dll` is the Intel graphics library which is loaded and attempting to handle the native calls from LWJGL.  This means there could be a problem with the current version of your Intel graphics card driver.  If running without mods does not resolve the issue the next thing to try is installing updated drivers for your Intel graphics card.  If you're running on a laptop and have a dedicated graphics card such as an nVidia in addition to the on-board card, then sometimes it's necessary to go into the nVidia control panel and tell Minecraft to always utilize the discrete graphics card.

Comment: The asker explicitly specifies in the question that there are no mods.