# Minecraft Error please help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I play minecraft. 
Recently minecraft had updated to 1.10 I switched from 1.9.4 to the recent update. Im able to enter minecraft just not my single player worlds nor mutyplayer. When I enter Im kicked out and shown this error:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[15:39:04] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: glasschandelier
[15:39:05] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: lastServer:
[15:39:05] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[15:39:06] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[15:39:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/ERROR]: Error in class 'LibraryLWJGLOpenAL'
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/ERROR]: Unable to initialize OpenAL.  Probable cause: OpenAL not supported.
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/WARN]: ERROR MESSAGE:
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: Could not locate OpenAL library.
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/WARN]: STACK TRACE:
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:156)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.libraries.LibraryLWJGLOpenAL.init(LibraryLWJGLOpenAL.java:164)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandNewLibrary(SoundSystem.java:1576)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandQueue(SoundSystem.java:2572)
[15:39:07] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.CommandThread.run(CommandThread.java:121)
[15:39:07] [Sound Library Loader/WARN]: ERROR MESSAGE:
[15:39:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Could not locate OpenAL library.
[15:39:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[15:39:08] [Thread-7/INFO]: Switching to No Sound
[15:39:08] [Thread-7/INFO]: (Silent Mode)
[15:39:08] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[15:39:09] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[15:39:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.10.2
[15:39:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[15:39:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[15:39:20] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 6%
[15:39:20] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity Pig that already exists with UUID 14f03dac-ca3d-4ebd-9fbb-e4ed8dcb3ad1
[15:39:20] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity Pig that already exists with UUID 3fa42a37-740f-479b-8174-1a55425b8a1f
[15:39:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 97%
[15:39:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
[15:39:21] [Server thread/INFO]: glasschandelier[local:E:5675e89d] logged in with entity id 113 at (-1687.0998380127874, 104.68313647380143, 284.1264813773241)
[15:39:21] [Server thread/INFO]: glasschandelier joined the game
[15:39:22] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity Rabbit that already exists with UUID 2ff4aba9-7513-47e8-afd0-b64c17084baf
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID bac6ef75-71cd-4f45-ab70-f88c7757f756
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID e8309acb-9bc4-415a-8c5f-c36c3d105f56
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID fdbb9382-1bc0-48a6-b713-50958076aad4
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID e29f5bdb-1220-428c-85ab-97094e0849a8
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID d282e30f-dbf5-4623-96cf-59629de8b417
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID 8138ed82-8f0e-4734-80ab-27dad7a3b914
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID 2aa36496-c531-416d-b9f2-618e4cb2b2df
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID 53f31a3d-2726-4c07-9953-cdc6b39117c0
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID 166edf45-ddac-465a-ae8b-f088414a848a
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity MinecartChest that already exists with UUID 5f38b3af-0908-43dc-ae15-303be1562ab2
[15:39:23] [Server thread/WARN]: Keeping entity Sheep that already exists with UUID bc8a3bea-ae4b-48ad-9659-5d95eb0cc149
[15:39:24] [Server thread/WARN]: Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded? Running 2405ms behind, skipping 48 tick(s)
```

Please Help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 3):

In my case these "can't keep up" messages never ran me into a client or server crash.
Just by the log output from the above shown log, there is no reason for you to be kicked out.

These duplicate IDs errors can be ignored, OR you can /tp these IDs to your location via /tp entity-id yourname - Then they will dissapear and never be seen again.

But still, none of the above should crash your connection, the server or the client. There are other reasons for that.

Comment: This is an old question. the issue is likely solved now.