# Why will my Minecraft on pc keep crashing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My minecraft always crashes when I hit the play it loads but then it comes back with a crash report and I can't even see the minecraft home screen. How can I fix this? My parents think someone has hacked into my minecraft.

```
Crash Report

---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't be sad, have a hug! <3              <<<< Whats this mean?

Time: 12/19/16 4:32 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at beq.ap(SourceFile:597)
    at beq.an(SourceFile:433)
    at beq.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at beq.ap(SourceFile:597)
    at beq.an(SourceFile:433)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at beq.a(SourceFile:380)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 75557872 bytes (72 MB) / 148910080 bytes (142 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.11
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: You're not running mods, but the error message seems to indicate the hardware you're running on doesn't support the required level of OpenGL, based on a quick google search.  What graphics hardware are you running this on?

Comment: I'll tell you this much: nobody has hacked your minecraft.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new question. Replacing this question with a completely different crash log for a different program (a MC server instead of the MC client!) is not how to ask a new question. (I removed the changes.)

Comment: sorry that was my only choice I couldn't ask a question until tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Your error code shows up in this question over [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft).

> org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated

Your graphics card or driver is unable to handle Minecraft.

There is a [help page](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/) that may have more information for you.

Comment: thanks so much I've been really wanting to play minecraft! but how can I fix the graphic card. do I have to buy one?

Comment: It depends on what you're running this on.  If you're running this on a laptop, you don't have a lot of options.  If you're on a desktop, this could be a driver or hardware issue.  The help page link on my answer has instructions that you can try to verify your OpenGL driver is correct.

Comment: My dad has Uninstalled my graphic card and now I cant play anything do you know how to fix this MADMAxJr? Or anyone who can help.

Comment: I corrected the help page link in my answer, it might not have worked before.  You have to have a video card and a driver that supports the OpenGL requirement.  That's all there is to it.