# When I try to make a direct connection to a LAN game in Minecraft, it says, "Connection Refused." Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I open a single player game to LAN with one user, and with the other user (in the same house) I try to direct connect to their port (192.168.1.102:60194) and it says, "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused:"
Anyone know what that means?

Comment: Look at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) post. De-bug for yourself.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong I don't see this error in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @TimmyJim It's there, yours is "Connection Refused" its the second thing I think.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong hmm... Not sure if that's exactly the same as this one but probably similar.  Right then.

Comment: @TimmyJim I came to the conclusion after I saw his quotes had "...Connection Refused:" <- There was probably something after the colon. (And if it was a statement it wouldn't be a colon, it would be a semi-colon)

Answer (score -1):

For a LAN World, you must be using the same means of connection as the player hosting it. If they are using WiFi, you must use the same WiFi as them.

Comment: This is very incorrect.  LAN games just need to be on the same network.  You don't have to use the same methodology.