# I can't join servers

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an Xbox One and I have the new version of Minecraft.

I tried playing on the servers but it keeps on saying that it's outdated and it couldn't connect to it. I can only connect to Lifeboat I want to play the other three but it won't let me and I don't understand why. Everything is updated I checked.

What else can I do about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Comment: For those voting as a duplicated, the other question is for Java/PC, this is Bedrock

Comment: Yes, but the answer is exactly the same for the two editions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you signed up using another device, and when you're trying to sign in onto the new one, it can't allow. Try using the one that you had signed up with.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be that the servers you are trying to connect to are outdated. They might not be running the same version of Minecraft you are. And to play on a Minecraft server the server and you have you have to be running the same version of Minecraft.

Answer (score -1):

In Minecraft servers, you usually have to be running the same kind of version that the server is. I suggest that you go on the server's website and find out what kind of version they're running, then switch to that one.