# Getting "NullPointerException" after upgrading Minecraft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

<sub>*This is surely not a new issue, but I can't resolve it using the questions already present:*</sub>

The launcher said there was an update available, so I upgraded it. Now I am getting this Java error:

```
      Minecraft has crashed!      
      ----------------------      
Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem.

--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT 7cf3a456 --------
Generated 5/1/19 8:02 PM

Minecraft: Minecraft 1.2.5
OS: Linux (amd64) version 4.15.0-48-generic
Java: 1.8.0_191, Oracle Corporation
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
LWJGL: 2.9.0
OpenGL: AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-48-generic, LLVM 6.0.0) 
version 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5, X.Org

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
    at adn.a(SourceFile:62)
    at adn.a(SourceFile:99)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(SourceFile:262)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:657)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
--- END ERROR REPORT 596c040e ----------
```

Curiously, the launcher can start the version 1.14 just fine (in demo mode, because money is tight!) but v1.2.5 (the latest full non-demo version) gives the above error. So something got messed up, but I can't determine what that is - so I can't fix it.

1. This was from v2.1.1321 to v2.1.1676.
2. running on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS
3. using OpenJDK 1.8, here is the "java -version" output:

   `openjdk version "1.8.0_191"`
   `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.16.04.1-b12)`
   `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)`
4. Nothing is logged into `/var/log/syslog` so it's not Java itself that crashes.
5. I can't find any `hs_err_pid*.log` that would yield more hints.
6. There's no log files in `~/.minecraft` that cover this time frame.

Comment: doubted. linked question simply asks for the errors, and said errors' fixes are out of date.

Comment: @EarthToAccess Perfect reason to edit the answer to update it, or post your own. It's also a canonical for that exact reason.

Comment: I did expand my question precisely because of the hint that I should do that if I didn't feel the dupe answers my issue. As it turns out, I found a solution that I will provide as an answer here. I'll see if I can integrate it into the canonical answer too, but it doesn't seem like a good fit there.

Comment: @Joachim and other close voters: Please don't close every error message question as duplicate of that. This has nothing to do with any of the error messages mentioned there.

Comment: @Fabian_Röling I noticed the *NullPointerException* in the title, found that same error in the linked question, so assumed a duplicate, especially since that linked thread wants to act as "a complete list of what error codes exist in Minecraft and how they occur, as well as how they can be resolved". That's not "nothing".

Comment: @FabianRöling (Still, to set the record straight (and not come off as antagonizing as I might have come across): I think the additional info the OP posted to distinguish it from the other questions/answers wasn't there at the time, and I didn't read through the error, since I'm not really familiar with the game or Java - i.e. I might have jumped to conclusions.)

Comment: @Joachim Ah ok, understandable then. But NullPointerException is a generic Java error, nothing Minecraft specific. It's the most common and most diverse error message in any Java program. It basically just means "some variable has no value and you're trying to do something with it".

Comment: @FabianRöling Thanks, I'll keep that in mind! And be more prudent with my flagging of Minecraft error questions :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

1. rename the `~/.minecraft` directory directory so Minecraft can't find it.
2. start Minecraft again and start a fresh game. This will generate a new `~/.minecraft` directory.
3. Exit Minecraft and copy the saved games from the renamed `~/.minecraft/saves` directory into the new one.
4. Start Minecraft again and confirm it's working now.

This did the trick for me!

As per the bug report linked below, the fix might be **even simpler than my steps** above:

1. edit `~/.minecraft/options.txt` and find the line starting with `lang=`. Note the parameter value is all lowercase.
2. Change the last two characters from lowercase to uppercase. E.g., change from `en_en` to `en_EN`.
3. Save and try Minecraft again.

Comment: This issue report gives you more information: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCL-5837 The solution suggested there is basically the same you already found.

Comment: Thank you Fabian! This tells me the fix is even simpler than what I did - literally just changing two characters in `options.txt`!