# Failed to login : The authentication are currently down for maintenance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I have the same problem but can still login to my account on my friends computer. i logged out and now cant log in as it says to connect to the internet and all my other stuff works because i am connected to the internet. help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

I did some research.

Unfortunately you will have to go through multiple solutions because some of them have worked for people but did not work for others. I will list all the solutions I found.

Try this:

- Make sure you are using the newest Minecraft launcher/client
- Sign in and out of your minecraft account from the launcher
- Take down any Firewalls or VPNs you may be using
- Flush your DNS and then unplug your router and then plug it back in
- Create a new profile on the Minecraft launcher and see if you still have the problem

If none of this works you could look it up on youtube. Or ask Mojang.