# How to fix java.lang.nullPointerException for my Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

As soon as my server boots up, it immediately crashes due to this error and I can't even play on my server. It's never done this before.

This is not a modded server, and this is vanilla.

CRASH log:

```
 C:\Users\syndi\Desktop\Elijah's Server But It's 1.14.4>java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.1.14.4.jar nogui
[12:05:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[12:05:32] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[12:05:32] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[12:05:32] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[12:05:32] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[12:05:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.14.4
[12:05:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[12:05:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[12:05:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[12:05:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[12:05:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[12:05:36] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
        at zs.a(SourceFile:507) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at zs.a(SourceFile:523) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at xz.g(SourceFile:146) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at uj.z(SourceFile:98) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at uj.<init>(SourceFile:25) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at uk.d(SourceFile:185) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:615) [server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:74) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at zs.a(SourceFile:505) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        ... 7 more
[12:05:37] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: C:\Users\syndi\Desktop\Elijah's Server But It's 1.14.4\.\crash-reports\crash-2020-02-29_12.05.36-server.txt
[12:05:37] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[12:05:37] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[12:05:37] [Server thread/ERROR]: Exception stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:546) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.m(SourceFile:574) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at uk.m(SourceFile:593) ~[server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:676) [server.1.14.4.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]

C:\Users\syndi\Desktop\Elijah's Server But It's 1.14.4>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Is that a modded server?

Comment: The NullPointerException occurs while trying to *stop* the server, not start it. And it tries to stop because of yet another error, something with a JSON file. Did you change anything since it last worked? For example I see single quotation marks (`'`) in the path, that looks like it could break something. It shouldn't, but maybe it does anyway. Also, try formatting the log (which is a crash log BTW, not a changelog): https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: @MechMK1 This is a vanilla server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231] Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Fix your JSON file. A config or data file somewhere is empty or malformed.

Comment: Do you know where the JSON file could be?

Comment: Nevermind, I found that multiple JSON files in the main server files was empty. Thank you for your help!