# What does Minecraft Launcher error code -111 mean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Previously, I've gotten the code -116, and then I thought I solved it, because it loaded me into my singleplayer survival world, but the game crashed. Now its giving me code -111, and I don't know why. I tried using the Minecraft installer to repair Minecraft, because that worked for code -116, but nothing changed except for the error code.

Comment: What is the error text? This may be helpful: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft

Comment: What caused and what solved the -116?

Answer (score 1):

Code 111 means that there is no connection, probably because of a firewall or over secure antivirus that is preventing it. If it is a firewall problem you need to get Minecraft unblocked by the administrator of that computer and if it's an antivirus you need to go into the app settings of your antivirus and manually whitelist Minecraft.