# Unable to connect to authserver.mojang.com

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

I recently got Minecraft to join a server with my friends, however, I kept getting the `failed to login the authentication are currently down for maintenance error`. I later realised this to be to due to my computer being unable to connect and ping authserver.mojang.com, as I was getting a `refused to connect` error. I thought this might be due to my router blocking the website, but I tried accessing the website from a different device on my network, and it worked fine. I've disabled my AV and Firewall, as well as changing my local IP address. I believe it is something to do with my computer, but I have no clue what.

Could anybody give me any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you able to access any other sites on the internet (google.com, microsoft.com, etc.)? This is probably a general network issue for your computer rather than a minecraft one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mojang servers often experience downtimes. Your issue is described in [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/96502/26132). Just try waiting for a bit, and if that doesn't work, make sure to check your *local* firewall.

1. This can be accessed by opening the Start Menu and typing "Windows Defender Firewall".

[image: Windows Defender Firewall in the Start Menu]

2. Then click "Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall".

[image: The button to click]

3. You should now be shown a list of applications with relevant tickboxes next to them.

[image: The interface for the setting mentioned above]

4. At the top right, click "Change Settings" and scroll down until you find "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" (there will likely be quite a few).

[image: Changing the settings]

5. Make sure the left tickbox on all instances is checked, now click the "OK" button at the bottom.

By doing this you have allowed JRE to connect to the internet. If this still doesn't work, try the following:

1. Press `win`+`r` to open the "Run" prompt.
2. Paste in `C:/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/DRIVERS/ETC` and press "OK".
3. Right-click on the file named "hosts" and open it with Notepad.
4. Check that the no hosts on `mojang.com` are in the hosts file, if there are, remove their lines.
5. Once you are done press `ctrl`+`s` **THIS PART IS IMPORTANT** and under the "Save a type" dropdown (below where you change the file name) click "All files".
6. Making sure to have done the above and not changed the file name, click "Save".
7. Try connecting to the auth servers now.

Comment: Tysm! I tried all the other options before, but I'd never seen anyone mention the hosts before! Turns out authserver.mojang.com was in there! Once I removed it, it worked fine!