# I can't join any servers and it says the authentication servers are currently offline

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

It shows - "the authentication servers are currently offline servers are currently offline". I just got Minecraft yesterday.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

It says "authentication servers" but anyway, it's an issue  currently happening, restarting your launcher and game usually fixes it, if it doesn't fix it then try restarting your computer. If its still not fixed just play single player until its fixed.