# 1.8.9 is crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I bet Cylons wouldn't have this problem.

Time: 1/1/21 4:30 PM
Description: Unexpected error

java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetError(GL11.java:1299)
    at ave.b(SourceFile:832)
    at ave.av(SourceFile:894)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:325)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.9
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 301543776 bytes (287 MB) / 536870912 bytes (512 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.8.9
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz
```

the exit error code is -1

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this ^^^^?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

Ppparently if you have a newer options.txt in .minecraft folder it can cause this problem try backing it up and re running. also i'd recommend MultiMC for running really old versions of minecraft for the same reason. also no way to accidentally open a world in the wrong version.

[source](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/java-edition-support/2935232-crash-playing-older-version-1-8-9)