# Vanilla MC Server Crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

```
[10:46:31] [main/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[10:46:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[10:46:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[10:46:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[10:46:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[10:46:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[10:46:31] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[10:46:32] [Worker-Main-14/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[10:46:32] [Worker-Main-14/INFO]: Loaded 927 advancements
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.16.5
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on (IP ADDRESS)
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[10:46:33] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[10:46:33] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
[10:46:33] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[10:46:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[10:46:33] [Server thread/ERROR]: Exception stopping the server
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:572) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.t(SourceFile:599) ~[server.jar:?]
        at zg.t(SourceFile:567) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:707) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:257) ~[server.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more info, such as system specs, and the server.properties file?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](https://meta.arqade.com/a/9944/4797)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) See **java.lang.NullPointerException** section of answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your server log complains:

```
**** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
```

The next line suggests a possible cause:

```
Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
```

Your computer has 65536 port numbers that are used to route incoming requests to a specific application that asked for that port—a program can't ask for a port that another program already has.

You might be running another Minecraft server instance on that port that you forgot to close, or your OS kernel may be (at least I know Linux does this, I'm not sure about other OS's) continuing to reserve the port for a few minutes because the last program to use it crashed uncleanly—this prevents bugs that happen in the lower-level network protocols when a connected client keeps trying to send data to a dead server, and a new server has already taken its place.

Restarting the machine the server is running on, or killing any live server processes and then waiting a few minutes, should resolve your issue.