# Minecraft question about servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

The authentication servers are down for maintenance so Minecraft failed to log in even though there are people on it. Please, I bought Minecraft but it doesn’t work. Is there something wrong with my computer?

Comment: Please do research before asking on Arqade, as this question has been answered multiple times. Additionally, please use proper grammar and formatting, as this is a formal website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) See the **Failed to login: the authentication servers are currently down for maintenance** section

Comment: In this case I suspect it's a PEBKAC error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly as it says it is: **the server (which your online account is stored on) is down for maintenance.** This means that they are repairing certain servers, which can cause certain players to go offline and fail to log on. *There is nothing you can do*, except wait until the server your account is stored on is repaired.