# "Failed to login: the authentication servers are currently down for maintenance." error message for months now

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

Yes, I've searched a lot about this question. Some of them tell me to wait, then I waited for a few months. And it didn't work. Some told me to change the Minecraft version, I tried from 1.7.10 to 1.17.1, none of them work. And I turned off my firewall. I tried a lot of things and this problem is still here. (The Minecraft log only shows `[time] [Client thread/INFO] [bcx]: Connecting to {}, ...`) (Mojang Service status always shows all servers are up.)

**UNTIL** I used my old computer to play - that worked! That's very weird! These two computers connect to the same network and router. I have no idea why that worked.

My OS is: **macOS High Sierra** 10.13.6 (17G14033).

Here is a log of 1.7.10 (with Java 1.8.0_321):

```
[09:24:18] [main/INFO]: Setting user: WhiteNightAWA
[09:24:18] [main/INFO]: (Session ID is token: ()) // I can't show you this... :(
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.attack:key.mouse.left
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.use:key.mouse.right
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.forward:key.keyboard.w
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.left:key.keyboard.a
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.back:key.keyboard.s
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.right:key.keyboard.d
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.jump:key.keyboard.space
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.sneak:key.keyboard.left.shift
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.sprint:key.keyboard.left.control
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.drop:key.keyboard.q
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.inventory:key.keyboard.e
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.chat:key.keyboard.t
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.playerlist:key.keyboard.tab
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.pickItem:key.mouse.middle
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.command:key.keyboard.slash
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.screenshot:key.keyboard.f2
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.togglePerspective:key.keyboard.f5
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.smoothCamera:key.keyboard.unknown
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.fullscreen:key.keyboard.f11
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.1:key.keyboard.1
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.2:key.keyboard.2
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.3:key.keyboard.3
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.4:key.keyboard.4
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.5:key.keyboard.5
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.6:key.keyboard.6
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.7:key.keyboard.7
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.8:key.keyboard.8
[09:24:19] [Client thread/WARN]: Skipping bad option: key_key.hotbar.9:key.keyboard.9
[09:24:19] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.1
[09:24:21] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[09:24:22] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[09:24:22] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x256 textures/blocks-atlas
[09:24:23] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 256x256 textures/items-atlas
[09:24:41] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to playdelta.gtnewhorizons.com., 25565 // (this is a 1.7.10 server)

// And it show the error here on the screen

[09:25:33] [Client thread/INFO]: Stopping!
```

and this is  on1.17.1 (with Java 16.0.2):

```
[09:47:39] [Render thread/INFO]: Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'


// yes I know this maybe the error but I have no idea about this...
[09:47:40] [Render thread/ERROR]: Failed to verify authentication
com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationException: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientException: Failed to read from https://api.minecraftservices.com/privileges due to PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientException.toAuthenticationException(MinecraftClientException.java:28) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:116) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.<init>(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:42) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilAuthenticationService.createSocialInteractionsService(YggdrasilAuthenticationService.java:151) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at dvp.a(SourceFile:670) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at dvp.<init>(SourceFile:429) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:179) [1.17.1.jar:?]
Caused by: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientException: Failed to read from https://api.minecraftservices.com/privileges due to PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:85) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:64) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:64) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:574) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1653) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1577) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527) ~[?:?]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308) ~[?:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.readInputStream(MinecraftClient.java:64) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.get(MinecraftClient.java:47) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    at com.mojang.authlib.yggdrasil.YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.checkPrivileges(YggdrasilSocialInteractionsService.java:104) ~[authlib-2.3.31.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
[09:47:40] [Render thread/INFO]: Setting user: WhiteNightAWA
[09:47:40] [Render thread/INFO]: Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.1 build 12
[09:47:41] [Render thread/ERROR]: Couldn't load pack metadata
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 4 column 14 path $.pack.pack_for
    at agv.a(SourceFile:495) ~[1.17.1.jar:?]
    at agv.a(SourceFile:545) ~[1.17.1.jar:?]
    at agv.a(SourceFile:553) ~[1.17.1.jar:?]
    at acs.a(SourceFile:74) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at acs.a(SourceFile:66) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at adg.a(SourceFile:37) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at adf.a(SourceFile:40) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at adi.g(SourceFile:45) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at adi.a(SourceFile:38) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at dvp.<init>(SourceFile:506) [1.17.1.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:179) [1.17.1.jar:?]
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 4 column 14 path $.pack.pack_for
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:716) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:739) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:739) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:714) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$35$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:910) ~[gson-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at agv.a(SourceFile:493) ~[1.17.1.jar:?]
    ... 10 more
[09:47:41] [Render thread/WARN]: Couldn't find pack meta for pack file/PANGU CONTINENT¸ê·½¥]¥¿¦¡ª©1.2.zip
[09:47:42] [Render thread/WARN]: Couldn't get pack info for: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
[09:47:43] [Render thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[09:47:54] [Render thread/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[09:47:54] [Render thread/INFO]: Sound engine started
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x1024x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 256x128x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/signs.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/banner_patterns.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shield_patterns.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 256x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/chest.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/beds.png-atlas
[09:47:55] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 512x256x4 minecraft:textures/atlas/shulker_boxes.png-atlas
[09:47:57] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/particles.png-atlas
[09:47:57] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 256x256x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/paintings.png-atlas
[09:47:57] [Render thread/INFO]: Created: 256x128x0 minecraft:textures/atlas/mob_effects.png-atlas
[09:48:03] [Server Pinger #2/ERROR]: Can't ping cusv.cc: Unknown host
[09:48:04] [Render thread/INFO]: Connecting to mc.hypixel.net, 25565
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Comment: This really isn't a technical support site.

Comment: @pppery Yes I saw that but I tried all `You can try:` in that error and that didn't work for me... (instead of the last one because the server is not host by me)

Comment: You've said that you're on High Sierra, that might be the reason, since their root certificate is dead, and you need to update it manually. What OS is your old computer on?

Comment: @Skye-AT That's Windows7... And I'm going to search how to update the certificate...

Comment: @WhiteNightAWA Well then it's 100% root certificate issue. Try this: [How do I update my root certificates on an older version of Mac OS (e.g. El Capitan)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422332/how-do-i-update-my-root-certificates-on-an-older-version-of-mac-os-e-g-el-capi)

Comment: I've read the logs. `[09:47:40] [Render thread/ERROR]: Failed to verify authentication
com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.AuthenticationException: com.mojang.authlib.exceptions.MinecraftClientException: Failed to read from https://api.minecraftservices.com/privileges due to PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification** path to requested target` referring that your computer doesn't have a verified certification.

Comment: @Skye-AT ya I'm trying to update that now.....

Comment: All of these comments are demonstrating exactly why this sort of question is not a good fit for the stack exchange network; it's become a one-on-one troubleshooting session of no value to anyone else, not a useful part of the [library of detailed answers to every question about videogames and videogame consoles we're trying to build](/tour)

Comment: @pppery No value to anyone else? I don't think so. There's plenty of users that is still using High Sierra (and older) MacOS. Root certificate is dead for everyone that is using High Sierra and older, because it got expired in October 2021. I can understand that it should be asked in Apple.SE or somewhere, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old versions of MacOS have some issues with certificate verification for Minecraft- Even if the root cert should be valid. Mojang only supports MacOS 10.14+. Sometimes macOS’s built-in updater breaks, check out this page for upgrade instructions: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683

Comment: This can also be caused by issues in the Hosts file, http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/hosts-file