# Minecraft fails to launch with "Problematic Frame" libobjc objc_msgSend

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, macos

Minecraft hasn't been working for a while now on my Mac. I've just been getting the same response over and over. Mods **or** Vanilla version of Minecraft won't work. I've tried deleting and downloading Minecraft, deleting and downloading Java, etc.

I keep getting problematic frames errors such as:

> Problematic frame:
> C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x671d]  objc_msgSend+0x1d
> to

> Problematic frame:
> C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x75a0]  objc_msgSend+0x20

Any idea on how to fix?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see a "problematic frame" error in your first image.  See the duplicate's answers, they both discuss what problematic frame is.  Also, the "Community" user is a bot.  Tagging them won't do anything.

Comment: Hello, I do not know what you mean by "duplicate's answers" can you please elaborate more on that? @TimmyJim

Comment: If you are talking about this https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft I scrolled down and I cannot find the exact error I have. Can you help? @TimmyJim

Comment: Problematic frames are almost always related to graphics.  Check your graphics drivers, make sure they are up to date. The exact error you have may not be in that post, but what errors are  in it almost certainly still translates to the same solution.

Comment: I cannot seem to find my Graphics Driver, I click the Apple at the top > About My Mac and I do not see Graphics on there is there a way to find/show my graphics drivers?

Comment: It seems to be something around Objective C - it's something pretty unique to Apple machines. I found https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-149225 which seems to be somewhat related.

Comment: I reopened since this particular problematic frames does not seem to be covered by the original duplicate