# Minecraft Error Exit Code 6 Problematic Error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-data-packs

I recently made a post and I was told that it was a Problematic error, but still don't get it. I run a MacBook Pro Moneterey and the Chip is an Apple M1. (don't know if needed) And I have tried all these options below

- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Reinstalling Java (I'm not entirely sure if I did it right or wrong.)
- Updating Mac

If you have any info of problematic info please tell me.
My problematic error changed from

> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x671d]  objc_msgSend+0x1d

to

> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x75a0]  objc_msgSend+0x20

I'm not entirely sure if those were even the correct Problematic Frame. If you need more images of the error I can try.

(EDIT I'm going to stop trying now, I would rather play a different game)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Error Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397975/minecraft-error-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-to-ena)

Comment: Reposting questions after they were closed is never the answer.

Comment: I'm new sorry, I just want to play Minecraft @pppery

Comment: As the [tour] says, the Stack Exchange network is about "build[ing] a library of detailed answers to every question about videogames and videogame consoles", It's not a technical support site, and your experience level and desires are irrelevant.