# Every time I try to log in to Minecraft it says failed to log in: Invalid session

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I'm playing Minecraft, and Suddenly I get kicked and it says Failed to log in: invalid session. I retry, and it says the same thing over and over. I restart my game, nothing. Even my launcher, nothing. I even switched to a client, but it still doesn't work.. Is there a fix?
Also, I didn't migrate my account because I can't. I tried restarting my computer, still didn't work. I'm on Lunar, and I don't know if that's a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) (could also be closed as technical support for modded Minecraft)

Comment: nope.. I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Exact same issue here, using unmigrated account and suddenly getting invalid session...
No response from Mojang, really hoping this isn't the final nail in the coffin for unmigrated accounts