# internal exception: java.net.socketexception: connection reset

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

So recently i made a minecraft server of my own and got my friends to join. It started giving us those connecton reset errors so i watched some tutorials and fixed it. My friend is still facing this issue. Whenever they join, they are falling from the sky (on their screen) and die but can't respawn. After a minute it kicks them out with this error: internal exception: java.net.socketexception: connection reset. I was thinking maybe it has something to do with the server setup but im not sure. There was nothing going on with the server while we tried to join and there's probably a problem with the server config. Could this be an ip issue or an internal one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Comment: @ppery that could be true but I'm still confused on how to fix that