# Minecraft Java Server Crash: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

My Minecraft Java Edition server has been crashing randomly with the "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION" error for the past two weeks. The crash occurs sometimes within 2 minutes and up to 6 hours after starting the server. During the first month after setting up the system, the server ran without any problems, and I haven't made any changes to the hardware since then. It is also notable that the server seems to be running completely fine on different hardware.

I have already tried multiple solutions over the past two weeks, which are listed below:

---

### Information about the system and the crash:

Main crash text:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffa5d8ba699, pid=2192, tid=7104
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.7+8) (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x6ca699]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Link with the hs_err_pid log: https://pastebin.com/HCDPwHTN

---

### What I've tried:

- Updating and trying different Java 17 OpenJDK builds
- Checking the RAM for any corruptions or malfunctions
- Updating every available Windows update
- Updating multiple drivers
- Tried other JVM-Arguments
- Trying to change some BIOS settings
- Replacing the graphic card with another one of the same model
- Reinstalling Windows and formatting the C disk.

---

### UPDATE: SOLUTION

I seem to have found the cause of the problem and wanted to share it, because I couldn't find anything anywhere about the solution that worked for me and maybe it will help someone. I'm not completely certain that the issue is resolved, but it's been over 24 hours without any errors. It appears that the problem was caused by CPU overclocking.

In the Asus BIOS I changed this CPU-Setting:

- CPU Core Ratio set to "Auto"

---

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Are you running a vanilla version or are you using any mods? Because that will be off-topic here.

Comment: I am using Purpur 1.19.2 with only plugins and no mods. The same server jar file and plugin versions are running fine on a different PC, making it less likely that they are the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does running any other (vanilla, any -kkit variant; Spigot/Paper/Bukkit/Sponge/etc. or Glowstone) exhibit the same behaviour, even if it is a blank server; seperate install/instance?

Comment: I am running Waterfall which crashes with a similar error log. I will try making a brand new Paper server but answering if that helped may take time because the crashes occur basically at random.

Comment: Error Log for Waterfall: https://pastebin.com/3K2qypGb

Comment: Server specs (VM? Guest/Host OS? RAM? CPU?) -;if everything crashes sounds like Java or hardware problem... Are you able to remote in and play Minecraft on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) Specifically, the [second answer's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203664/163757) section that is titled *Problematic frame: jvm.dll*

Comment: Is it possible that your machine is running out of memory?