# "The authentication are currently down for maintenance" in Minecraft Java Edition when connecting to a LAN IP address

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've read the other answers with the same title, but none of their creators encountered this when connecting to another LAN device directly via an IP address and port.

I'm using https://flathub.org/apps/org.prismlauncher.PrismLauncher. My network configuration is:

> [image]

I'm connecting to a static IP address of another computer on my LAN (`192.168.0.4`) whose world has been "opened to LAN" via port `46167` (for instance — it changes each time the world is opened, and I adjust my commands accordingly). I can ping that PC at any port, including that port:

> ```
> RokeJulianLockhart@s1e8h4:~> sudo nping --tcp -p 80 192.168.0.5
>
> Starting Nping 0.7.94 ( https://nmap.org/nping ) at 2024-02-17 12:40 GMT
> SENT (0.0454s) TCP 192.168.0.4:36939 > 192.168.0.5:80 S ttl=64 id=7329 iplen=40  seq=2173434914 win=1480 
> RCVD (0.0456s) TCP 192.168.0.5:80 > 192.168.0.4:36939 RA ttl=128 id=0 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
> SENT (1.0456s) TCP 192.168.0.4:36939 > 192.168.0.5:80 S ttl=64 id=7329 iplen=40  seq=2173434914 win=1480 
> RCVD (1.0458s) TCP 192.168.0.5:80 > 192.168.0.4:36939 RA ttl=128 id=1 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
> SENT (2.0468s) TCP 192.168.0.4:36939 > 192.168.0.5:80 S ttl=64 id=7329 iplen=40  seq=2173434914 win=1480 
> RCVD (2.0469s) TCP 192.168.0.5:80 > 192.168.0.4:36939 RA ttl=128 id=2 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
> SENT (3.0473s) TCP 192.168.0.4:36939 > 192.168.0.5:80 S ttl=64 id=7329 iplen=40  seq=2173434914 win=1480 
> RCVD (3.0474s) TCP 192.168.0.5:80 > 192.168.0.4:36939 RA ttl=128 id=3 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
> SENT (4.0485s) TCP 192.168.0.4:36939 > 192.168.0.5:80 S ttl=64 id=7329 iplen=40  seq=2173434914 win=1480 
> RCVD (4.0486s) TCP 192.168.0.5:80 > 192.168.0.4:36939 RA ttl=128 id=4 iplen=40  seq=0 win=0 
>  
> Max rtt: 0.141ms | Min rtt: 0.085ms | Avg rtt: 0.126ms
> Raw packets sent: 5 (200B) | Rcvd: 5 (230B) | Lost: 0 (0.00%)
> Nping done: 1 IP address pinged in 4.11 seconds
> ```

...because both its and my firewalls have been disabled:

> ```
> RokeJulianLockhart@s1e8h4:~> systemctl status firewalld
> ○ firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
>      Active: inactive (dead)
>        Docs: man:firewalld(1)
>
> Feb 17 10:17:37 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
> Feb 17 12:27:31 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
> Feb 17 12:27:32 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Deactivated successfully.
> Feb 17 12:27:32 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
> Feb 17 12:27:32 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Consumed 1.275s CPU time.
> Feb 17 12:28:01 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
> Feb 17 12:28:01 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
> Feb 17 12:30:34 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
> Feb 17 12:30:34 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Deactivated successfully.
> Feb 17 12:30:34 s1e8h4 systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
> RokeJulianLockhart@s1e8h4:~>
> ```

The other client is Windows 11 Home, mine is

> ```
> PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart> cat -vbET '/etc/os-release' | grep 'CPE_NAME'
>      9  CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20240131:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"$
>     11  #CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:tumbleweed:20240131"$
> PS /home/RokeJulianLockhart>
> ```

I'd be glad for any assistance, even an explanation of why Minecraft believes it even has the capability to poll a verification server, and why that's necessary to connect via LAN.

Comment: Hi Roke, are your instances of Minecraft modded?

Comment: Indeed, @Joachim — I was running https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/roguelike-adventures-and-dungeons/files/4747793 on https://flathub.org/apps/org.prismlauncher.PrismLauncher. Switching to a non-modded release of 1.20.4 on the same launcher remediated the issue. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per ["The authentication are currently down for maintenance" in Minecraft Java Edition when connecting to a LAN IP address](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/406239/the-authentication-are-currently-down-for-maintenance-in-minecraft-java-editio#comment570118_406239), I was using https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/roguelike-adventures-and-dungeons/files/4747793 when I encountered this problem. Switching to an unmodified instance of 1.20.4 remediated this specific error.

---

The sole permanent solution has been to use an online account during initial LAN connection, because although the mods caused Minecraft to believe that the authentication servers were "down for maintenance", attempting to join a LAN game without an InterNet connection causes it to state that it is *unable* to connect to the authentication servers instead. Relevantly, solely one user being connected to the InterNet causes it to state that the session is invalid.

Once connected, the InteNet connection is unnecessary. I've consequently filed https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-268676.